# Incompatible element type Time for collection of Datetime for BusinessHours

Tags: apex, businesshours

I working to calculate the business hours from the Business day:

```
List<BusinessHours> bhList = [SELECT FridayEndTime,FridayStartTime,Id,IsActive,IsDefault,LastModifiedById,
                              LastModifiedDate,MondayEndTime,MondayStartTime,Name,SaturdayEndTime,
                              SaturdayStartTime,SundayEndTime,SundayStartTime,SystemModstamp,ThursdayEndTime,
                              ThursdayStartTime,TimeZoneSidKey,TuesdayEndTime,TuesdayStartTime,
                              WednesdayEndTime,WednesdayStartTime FROM BusinessHours where Name='XXXX Hours'];
        System.debug('SIZE :: '+bhList.size());
        Integer businessHr = 0;
        List<Datetime> brStartTime = new List<Datetime>();
        List<Date> brEndTime = new List<Date>();
        for(BusinessHours br : bhList){
            brStartTime.add(br.MondayStartTime);
            brEndTime.add(br.MondayEndTime);
        }

        Integer diff = brEndTime.[0] - brStartTime.[0];
        System.debug('diff :: '+diff);
```

I am getting the below error:

```
Incompatible element type Time for collection of Datetime
```

Comment: are you still looking for answers?

Answer (score 0):

`MondayStartTime` is type of `Time` where you are storing them in `DateTime List`. You need to change your list type to time.

```
List<time> brStartTime = new List<time>();
List<time> brEndTime = new List<time>();
```

[BusinessHours](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_businesshours.htm)